# How to set browser confirm box focus on cancel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to keep the default focus on cancel in confirm box. The browser based confirm box has default focus on OK. How can i alter it using java script.

Comment: You simply cannot override this.

Comment: You can achieve this by using a simple modal. Try [this](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change that. It's a behaviour which is dependant on the browser and/or OS at a level *much* lower than JS code has access to.

If you need to achieve this, I'd suggest using a library which overwrites the standard `confirm()` behaviour with a HTML-based modal which can be amended in whatever manner you require.

Comment: I've never done this personally, so can't recommend any. There does appear to be a *lot* of them if you Google.

Comment: @Ashutoshdwivedi the number of options are unlimited including simply writing your own, and it is based on your needs, I would suggest a google search

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Sure.

Comment: `Sweet Alert` maybe

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  This is simply under the browsers control - [the spec for `confirm`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-confirm) says the browser has to:

> Show message to the user, and ask the user to respond with a positive or negative response.

It's entirely up to the browser how it does that, and you can't affect it from JavaScript.